# How do I copy from keyword to keyword in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, file, io

How might I copy lines keyword by keyword in one file fileA to another file fileB in Python 2.7? The query should include the keywords in the output.

Comment: You want to copy a file to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question was to copy part of the original file which is between startWord and endWord, you can use this which is very slightly modified from 
[Extract subset of file in bash or Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345334/extract-subset-of-file-in-bash-or-python)

```
begin = 'BEGINSTRING'
end = 'ENDSTRING'

with open(f, 'r') as input_file:
  tmp = []
  flag = False

  for line in input_file.readlines():

    if begin in line:            
      flag = True
      index = line.find(begin)
      tmp.append(line[index:])
      continue
    elif flag:
      tmp.append(line) 
    elif end in line:
      index = line.find(end)             
      tmp.append(line[:index+1]) 
      break
    else:
      pass

with open(f + '_new', 'w') as output_file:
  for line in tmp:
  output_file.write(line)
```

Comment: If I wanted to add strip(), to begin and end...how might I do so? I'm looking for an exact phrase.

Comment: @CookiesMonster I didn't completely understand what you want to use strip() on. 

If you want to use it for the start and end words, you can use it in line 1 and 2 i.e begin = 'BEGINSTRING'.strip() and similarly for end..... .

If you wanted to strip characters from the final subset from the file, you can use tmp.strip() after the for loop and before we write into the new file.

Comment: That's perfect. :) The only thing is...it doesn't recognize the end string even if I do this: ENDSTRING.strip() ? The new file is just a copy of the original file? IE: It doesn't match with the end string.